# Get user registration date - open graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have looked through the Open graph docs but am unable to find any info on whether you can see the date a user has registered on facebook.

Looking on here (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) I cannot find anything.

Does anyone know if this data is available?

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this data is not available. The best you can do is pull the oldest action taken by the user that is available by the API. Most of the times it is a status post.